# `npx cypress verify` causing multi-arch image build to fail with `docker buildx` - can build locally on ARM & AMD archs

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress, npx, buildx

While trying to create a multi-arch Docker image for us to run Cypress in, we are having some issues getting the build to go through using the `docker buildx` command.  We use this for all of our other multi-arch images without an issue, but for the Cypress one we are getting the following errors for the build that doesn't correspond with the machine creating it.  Below is the error message when run on an Apple M1 MacbookPro.  As you can see, the `linux/amd64` build is failing.  When we do the same command from an Apple Intel MacbookPro, we get the identical error, but for the `linux/arm64` build.

**Docker Build Command:**
`docker buildx build -t my-multi-arch-cypress-image -f Dockerfile-cypress-arm . --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64  --push`

**Error in terminal:**

```bash
[+] Building 9.2s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.5s
 => => starting container buildx_buildkit_cs-builder0                                                                                                                                                                                      0.5s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-cypress-arm                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 627B                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 66B                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1                                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 => [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1                                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 => [linux/amd64 1/4] FROM docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1@sha256:e7a640bfdc4a2d0abc64943a874d3b02e0b15ce37e8e07872e00ee02393abbfb                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1@sha256:e7a640bfdc4a2d0abc64943a874d3b02e0b15ce37e8e07872e00ee02393abbfb                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 1/4] FROM docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1@sha256:e7a640bfdc4a2d0abc64943a874d3b02e0b15ce37e8e07872e00ee02393abbfb                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/cypress/base:16.18.1@sha256:e7a640bfdc4a2d0abc64943a874d3b02e0b15ce37e8e07872e00ee02393abbfb                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 2/4] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 3/4] RUN npm install cypress@12.4.1                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [linux/amd64 4/4] RUN npx cypress verify                                                                                                                                                                                         6.6s
 => CACHED [linux/arm64 2/4] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm64 3/4] RUN npm install cypress@12.4.1                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm64 4/4] RUN npx cypress verify                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 > [linux/amd64 4/4] RUN npx cypress verify:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#0 5.346 [STARTED] Task without title.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#0 6.535 [FAILED] Cypress failed to start.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#0 6.535 [FAILED]                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#0 6.535 [FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies                                                                                                                               
#0 6.535 [FAILED] 
#0 6.535 [FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.
#0 6.535 [FAILED] 
#0 6.535 [FAILED] ----------
#0 6.535 [FAILED] 
#0 6.535 [FAILED] qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
#0 6.535 [FAILED] qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
#0 6.535 [FAILED] qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#0 6.535 [FAILED] 
#0 6.535 [FAILED] ----------
#0 6.535 [FAILED] 
#0 6.535 [FAILED] Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.5)
#0 6.535 [FAILED] Cypress Version: 12.4.1
#0 6.541 Cypress failed to start.
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 Please refer to the error below for more details.
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 ----------
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
#0 6.541 qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
#0 6.541 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 ----------
#0 6.541 
#0 6.541 Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.5)
#0 6.541 Cypress Version: 12.4.1
------
Dockerfile-cypress-arm:22
--------------------
  20 |     # running this command separately from "cypress run" will also cache its result
  21 |     # to avoid verifying again when running the tests
  22 | >>> RUN npx cypress verify
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npx cypress verify" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is the Dockerfile I am using to build this image:

```
FROM cypress/base:16.18.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install cypress@12.4.1

RUN npx cypress verify
```

I am able to build this locally on either M1 or Intel to work on that corresponding machine, but our team works with both chips, so we need the multi-arch build to go through in order for our entire team to be able to run Cypress tests locally without having to build the image locally themselves.

I've been working on this for a couple weeks now, finally getting it to run for ARM architecture, but now I am stuck on this final piece of the puzzle, and I'm just totally at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with help from the Cypress team.  They recommended just removing the `cypress verify` command from my docker-file, the same as they do for all `arm64` builds.  After removing this line, everything works as planned.

You can read their full response [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/issues/833).